# How about fitting into gaming industry with Design and Development mindset and seeking for a masters degree?

Tags: game-design, graphics, ui-design, education

Might be the question is a bit weird but that's what I'm focused on and want to discuss about obtaining a masters degree to fulfill my dreams to work as both designer and developer.

I work as a programmer with 5 years of experience and I code in C, C++, C#. Back home I design Application UX, Logo, Banners, Website graphics, Write small software for personal needs or friends and yes I like to play games.

Now, holding a bachelor degree in Computer science and professional experience I want to opt for a Masters degree abroad(probably in Europe) with focused subject(may be Game design/development). Now my problem is that I do not like to do a formal Computer science masters as it would be a traditional process of learning computer systems. As well as I don't like mathematics in dept, having said that I do use calculation and business logic a lot in my programs but I'm not very much fond of them. So basically I'm a design creativity guy with developer mindset. I developed quite a few windows applications on my own and some of them are live on Softpedia.

So I like to pursue my future with the mix of both. Is there any way for me to fit into game industry? If not what would be better for me rather than continue only programming job profile?

Comment: If you want to develop games, you need math. And a lot of math.

Comment: Check out unity3d.com  you can get a good overview of the game development industry, also check the tutorials and you will see if your knowledge and skills are suited for it

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a two part question.

> Where could I fit into the gaming industry?

As the gaming industry is still quite new, I'd say it's still quite flexible as to how you would go about getting into it. There is a lot of tips on this if you do a google search. Basically tho, since the rise of indie development, there are two routes:

- Apply for a job at a company, these come in all sizes, from one to thousands of people. Sure a nice degree will help you, especially for the bigger companies, but the most important part I'd say is that you can showcase your skills through a portfolio or experience. If you are really good at something, you will be able to get a job, and this is especially true in the gaming industry.
- Go indie. i.e. start on your own and make games, or join others who are doing the same. This is a very popular route in the past years and very many people are doing it, thus there is a lot of competition, not to mention that finishing a game, getting it sold and running a company are huge challenges. It's become easier tho with easy to learn tools such as Unity and Unreal engine, and distribution platforms such as Steam and the appstore.

> What masters degree should I take to focus my game developer career?

I think this question is very country & university specific as you are a bit limited to where you are willing to study. Say you can study anywhere in the world. Looking through the whole worlds university programmes is quite a daunting taks, but I'd search for any schools offering game development bachelors and see what they offer in masters degrees.

Masters degrees tend to be a bit more specific tho, and I think you'd end up choosing a specialty that isn't really game specific, but rather computer engineering.

In the end tho, as I stated in the answer above, if you really want to get into the industry you should really just become really good at what your doing and build a portfolio and apply for jobs. I think that would help you a lot more than a degree.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will edit the question a bit according to your points. But in brief I'm looking forward to a Master degree abroad specially in Europe. And currently I'm well placed in my country within the IT industry which I'm doing for the past 5+ years.